# Finding polygon by certain points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

[image][image: How to find polygon by certain points in QGIS]

I am using QGIS 2.8.6 in Windows and I need to find polygon by certain points.

In the picture are red polygons and blue points. Some polygons have points but some don't.

How do I quickly find the polygons with points?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 6):

Activate the **Spatial Query** plugin.

Then run it from Vector menu:

Source layer: polygons

Reference layer: points

Where: Intersects

Comment: Can you accept the answer from @pnz and perhaps upvote it as well if it has solved your question?

Comment: don't know how to accept the answer,can you tell me how to do it.